# Do I always need to duplicate and nest data to refer to it in noSQL (Firebase)?

Tags: firebase, database-design, nosql

I haven't exactly worked with SQL a lot, but apparently enough to be gripped by its claws, because I'm rather at a loss on how to refer to things in noSQL.

Let's say I have a page displaying `books`, and then a feature where `users` can save any amount of books to their own personal libraries ("liking" them, essentially).

A book comprises parameters like **author**, **title**, **amount of pages**, **synopsis**, **list of characters**, etc.

In SQL I would need to set up a join table between `books` and `users`, but in noSQL (and specifically Firebase because that's what I'm starting with) there's no such thing and that leaves me puzzled. I have been warned to nest data, but here it seems necessary to nest `books` under `users` (or vice versa?) and have a lot of duplicated data.

This seems icky to me for several reasons. One is that it would require a lot of extra time to iterate over users, because their entire library would need to be iterated over as well. Second, I would need to duplicate a lot of data, because I want to display the books in their library in full, along with the synopsis and character lists, etc.

Do I actually need to make another segment, called `library`, where I list `users` and nest their `books` under them? Is that a valid approach?

Or have I missed something essential here? Can I actually refer to data as with a foreign key even in noSQL (including Firebase)?

Comment: See also: [structuring data](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/structuring-data.html) and [understanding data](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/understanding-data.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into the same issues coming from a SQL background. The example structure below is a very high-level view of what your noSQL, in this case Firebase, may best look like:

```
- Firebase root
    - Users
        - $userId
            - name
            - email
            - books
                - $bookId
    - Books
        - $bookId
            - title
            - author
```

...and a very simple idea of how you'd access books:

```
var ref = new Firebase();
ref.child('Books').child($bookId).push({/* book info */});
```

In summary, those `$userId` and `$bookId` fields become very important to reference data throughout your app.

Comment: Doesn't it take a lot of time to iterate through users?

Comment: I'd set up a User Service and a Book Service in this case and inject them into controllers as needed. You could then pull user details in the controller by utilizing the User Service, and follow that by calling the Book Service to retrieve that user's books (based on `$bookId`'s). Sure, if there are hundreds of books associated with a user it could take a little time, but in general it shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: I see, thanks! And I just realized I don't exactly have to iterate through the users list. Can I just get your thought on making a `library`, if that approach is too "out there" or valid?

Comment: Meaning each user has a "library" of all their books?

Comment: Yeah exactly, so there would be a library, which holds all users, which holds their books.

Comment: Regardless, I think your way is better. I was just curious. :)

Comment: That's another option, but my recommendation would be to keep Users and Books separate and reference them by id ($userId, $bookId).